# implement code in unprotected and protected sheets VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

when I am trying to execute this code it only executes the part after `Exit Sub` , only the foreach loop is executed, when the sheet is unprotected. I think it is caused by the `Exit Sub`. My problem is that I want to execute to different codes one when the sheet is protected (`for each cell in Range("B6:B112..`)) and the other(starting at `Dim rng as Range`..) when the sheet is unprotected. I tried `If..Then..Else` but that does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Worksheets("test").ProtectContents Then Exit Sub

 For Each cell In Range("B6:B112")
 If cell.Value <> "" Then
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Else
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
 Next cell

 Dim rng As Range
 Dim eingabeNr As Double, letzteZeile As Long, eingabeDatum As String, eingabeNrString As String
 Set rng = Range("D:BC")
```

THX.

Comment: Why does `If..Then..Else` not work?

Comment: I am not really sure where to put the `If..then..else` tried a lot but it does not work @YowE3K

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Worksheets("test").ProtectContents = True Then 'added = true for readability.

   For Each cell In Range("B6:B112")
       If cell.Value <> "" Then
           cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Else
           cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
   Next cell
Else
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim eingabeNr As Double, letzteZeile As Long, eingabeDatum As String,_
   eingabeNrString As String
   Set rng = Range("D:BC")

   Do some stuff here

End if
```

Comment: then I implement it like your code. I get an error at `cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False` @Luuklag

Comment: It might be because the row is not hidden, so you can't unhide it. Just remove the line from the code, as it would have no function.